# Why does JVM program run much faster with a Smaller heap size settings?

Tags: java, jvm

I am benchmarking a JVM application which puts very heavy load on both disk IO and CPU.

Normally I benchmark it using 4G max/min heap size, the whole benchmark suit takes in average 73 seconds to run.

Today I was curious and gave it only 1G max/min heap size, and surprisingly the whole benchmark suit takes only 62 seconds to run in average.

So I wonder why does JVM perform better with a smaller heap size?

Extra notes:

- The above benchmark results are reliably reproducible on this machine.
- Benchmark source code https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/Aurinko2/blob/master/src/test/scala/net/houzuo/aurinko2/test/logic/Benchmark.scala

Environment:

```
java version "1.7.0_19"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (fedora-2.3.9.1.fc17-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Linux ____ 3.8.4-102.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Mar 24 13:09:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs on Oracle JVM, the note says

> Next, you might try decreasing the amount of heap used. A larger heap
>   will cause garbage collection pauses to increase because there is more
>   heap to scan.

It is also function of GC algorithm you use. For example incremental GC may give completely different numbers. (Try  `-Xincgc` and see your numbers)

[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html)

Comment: thank you for that, my apologize that I did not mention my JVM environment. Does OpenJDK have similar behaviour?

Comment: @ Howard Guo - It is really function of JRE not JDK. I expect Oracle and OpenJDK to have similar behavior here. GC etc share same code.